# How to link my custom Timepicker to my asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have made a custom timepicker, but i have made it in a html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//here goes my script
 </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
//here are my form and div's
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to use this in my asp.net page how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use asp.net usercontrol instead of html page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx

You can include into your page this way: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: i dont want to crete any server control i just want to link my custom *.js file along with its html into my asp.net page

Comment: You can inject html into your page with JQuery append: http://api.jquery.com/append/